# How to split numpy array values with comma

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have used pandas data frame to make a table. I want to draw lines b/w each column because I have to copy this data on microsoft office or Latex and I have to show it in table form. How can I do that?

```
`x= [0,1,2,3,4]
y=[10,20,30,40,50]
z= [100,200,300,400,500]
dict = {"col_1": x, "col_2":y, "col_3":z}
print(pandas.DataFrame(data=dict))`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to copy this table to MS Office, you can try two things :

1) Write the dataFrame to a csv file and open the csv file in MS Office.

```
df=pandas.DataFrame(data=dict)
df.to_csv("my_df.csv")
```

2) If you really want the lines between the columns, you can also write it to a html file and open it.

```
df.to_html("my_df.html")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried above command but it is giving me error that AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: I copied the same lines as you have mentioned

Comment: @herry Please add the EXACT code you typed in your question itself

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the following code, then you may open df.xlsx in MS Excel.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4]   
y = [10,20,30,40,50]
z = [100,200,300,400,500]
_dict = {"col_1": x, "col_2":y, "col_3":z}
```

Saving dataframe to xlsx:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=_dict)  
df.to_excel('df.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy a table into Excel (etc.) without intermediate steps like saving and loading, simply use the pandas `to_clipboard()` method:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html

Or to apply the OP's example:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [10,20,30,40,50]
z = [100,200,300,400,500]
dict = {"col_1": x, "col_2":y, "col_3":z}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=dict)
df.to_clipboard()
```

Following this it should be possible to paste directly into a spreadsheet or other relevant software.

The OP's original question also asked for the option to use in LaTeX. This can be achieved in a similar fashion with the following:

```
print(df.to_latex(index=False))
```

This doesn't automatically end up in the clipboard but does print:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule
{} &  col\_1 &  col\_2 &  col\_3 \\
\midrule
0 &      0 &     10 &    100 \\
1 &      1 &     20 &    200 \\
2 &      2 &     30 &    300 \\
3 &      3 &     40 &    400 \\
4 &      4 &     50 &    500 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Note that without `print`ing the outputs of `to_latex()` there will be extra backslashes in the output if you are using something like Jupyter that prints returns as default, so the `print` is necessary.